# Selecting new value from form using watin

Tags: winforms, watin

I have
Watin.Core.teaxfield my date = x.textfield(find.byid("whatever"))
My date.value=2014-06-06"....this will set the value
My question is how can I select the value from a label or combo box that is is my windows form .thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a combobox, you can select a value using something such as:

```cs
SelectList selectList = browser.SelectList(Find.ById("some_id"));
selectList.Option("some_option").Select();
```

To get a label value:

```cs
string value = browser.Label(Find.ById("some_id").Text;
```

Comment: Thanks,but the combo box or label value are in my windows form, I need to pass the value that I either select or write so it can find the same value in the website.  This website uses a lot of js

Comment: It if the website were reg HTML I could do it but this one use a lot of dynamic content. I am trying to set the value at their end by selecting one from my windowsform